# How to prevent duplicate record into mysql?

Tags: mysql, unique, duplicate-data

I have a Name and a Date entry.

how do i make a unique date if the Name are same?

Comment: You will need to create [unique constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html) and use the [`ON DUPLICATE KEY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) facility

Comment: Beyond this, we will need _lots more_ information about what you're trying to do and what you've done already.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a UNIQUE index on (Name, Date).

Answer (score 0):

Check if the available name _date combination is present in database or not......before inserting new record in the database..

if entry is present than show the alertbox else enter the record